# How to add data into nested array in mongoose using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I wanted to add data in 'replies'.

[image]

I tried this, but it's not work

```
router.post("/addReply", async (req, res) => {
  const { rply, postedBy, id, cmntId } = req.body;


  const newReply = { reply: rply, postedBy: postedBy };

  await topix
    .findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: id, "comments.cmnt._id": cmntId },
      {
        $addToSet: {
          "comments.cmnt.replies": newReply,
        },
      },
      (err) => {
        if (err) {
          res.send({ message: "comment not posted" });
        } else {
          res.send({ message: "comment posted" });
        }
      }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Documents in collection:

```json
[
   {
     "_id": 1,
     "comments":[
       {
         "_id": 1001,
        "cmnt":"good work",
         "replies":[{ id: 100001, "content":"cool"}]
       },
       {
         "_id": 1002,
        "cmnt":"apple",
         "replies":[{ id: 200001, "content":"bad apple"}]
       }
     ]
   }
]
```

See [Update Elements Match `arrayFilters` Criteria](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/#update-elements-match-arrayfilters-criteria)

```
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: 1 },
  {
    $addToSet: {
      "comments.$[element].replies": {
        id: 100002,
        content: "ok",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    returnNewDocument: true,
    arrayFilters: [
      { "element._id": 1001 },
    ],
  }
);
```

Results:

```json
[
  {
    _id: 1,
    comments: [
      {
        _id: 1001,
        cmnt: "good work",
        replies: [
          {
            id: 100001,
            content: "cool",
          },
          { id: 100002, content: "ok" },
        ],
      },
      {
        _id: 1002,
        cmnt: "apple",
        replies: [
          {
            id: 200001,
            content: "bad apple",
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

[MongoDB playground](https://www.humongous.io/app/playground/mongodb/647049637ab68a5f4d10f144)